# android : intersection portion of two image button not clickable for second image button

Tags: android, imagebutton, transparent, intersection

i have two custom transparent image Buttons which i make the transparent area not clickable and worked fine with me but the transparent portions of second image button intersect with the first one , and my problem is that this transparent portion make the behind area of first image button not clickable , how to make this intersection area work and clickable?

[image]